# jsp directly jumps to html rather than through servlet

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, httpsession

I made an web app which has the **login** and **logout** functions.

The first time I login and logout seems normal.

But when I change another account and repeat above operations,

the logout operation directly jumps to the `index.html` rather than through

the `LogoutServlet.java`. So the session is still valid.

Do you know the reason?

I'll be appreciated that you tell me the reason.

There are my key codes as following.

`LoginServlet.java`

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session!=null) 
            session.setAttribute("LoginUser", user);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp")
                   .forward(request, response);
```

`home.jsp`

`<a href="Logout.action">Logout</a>`

`LogoutServlet.java`

```
@WebServlet("/Logout.action")
protected void doGet(...) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session!=null) {
        session.removeAttribute("LoginUser");
        session.invalidate();
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html").forward(request, response);
}
```

You can try it on my website. http://anwuli.cn/HelloWorld

Provided 2 test accounts.

format: username&password

First: admin&123456

Second: anpeng&123456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the previous answer has mentioned. You are not creating a new session if one doesn't exist when you check if there is a session with:

```
request.getSession(false)
```

So the if block is not true when a logged in account tries to logout:

```
 if(session!=null) {
        session.removeAttribute("LoginUser");
        session.invalidate(); // this code never runs...
    }
```

You need to either use:

```
HttpSession session = (request.getSession());
```

or

```
HttpSession session =  request.getSession(true)
```

Also, a session is created anytime a new user connects to your website (even if they have not logged in.)

So you need to check if the attribute is null like this:

```
 if(null == session.getAttribute("LoginUser")){  
         //no logged in user
         RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp"); //replace with your login page  
           rd.forward(request,response);    
           return;
    }else{
         //user attribute is not null so logout
        session.invalidate();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);` so you don't create any **new** session in the `LoginServlet.java`.

Where do you create your **first** session ?